# Can I use the gmail "+ filter" to "login" via pop3 or IMAP

Tags: gmail, pop3

I know that gmail allows you to differentiate mails If I append a + when subscribing to a mailing list and filter it accordingly in the web client. But I was wondering if it was possible for when I check mail through pop3 to "login in" into mymail+ml@gmail.com as a way to only get those mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible I'm afraid.

The reason for this is that it is the part without the + that is your actual Google user ID.

The + and whatever is after it is simply a convenient shortcut (that is allowed in several email systems). It is only used for filtering **after** you have authenticated (logged in) to the system.

What might help you is to add an automatic filter to GMail to move those emails into a folder then you can quickly see only those emails even from a non-Gmail interface such as Thunderbird or Outlook.